# Sr Lock on created gdb is not releasing

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects, java, server-object-extension

My problem is sr lock is not releasing on gdb , also please see that code can be improved?

Below is my code

```
public String exportGDB(String whereClause,IServerObjectHelper serverObjectHelper)  // returns the path of GDB
{
        String tempPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        SOEHelper soeHelper = new SOEHelper();      
        String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".gdb";

        try 
        {
            // Create a FileGDB workspace factory           
            IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactory();



            // Create a new File geodatabase
            IWorkspaceName workspaceName = workspaceFactory.create(tempPath,fileName , null, 0);

            IName wsName = (IName) workspaceName;

            IWorkspace workspace = new IWorkspaceProxy(wsName.open());

            IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = new IFeatureWorkspaceProxy(workspace);

            IMapLayerInfos layerInfos = soeHelper.getLayerInfo(serverObjectHelper); 

            IQueryFilter qf = new QueryFilter();
            qf.setWhereClause(whereClause);



            IFeatureClass fc = null;
            IMapLayerInfo layerInfo = null;
            IFeatureClass gdbFeatureClass = null;
            IFeature newFeature = null;
            IFeature feature = null;
            IFeatureCursor  featureCursor = null;


            for (int i=0; i < layerInfos.getCount(); i++)
            {
                layerInfo = layerInfos.getElement(i);

                fc = soeHelper.getFeatureClass(layerInfo.getID(), serverObjectHelper);              
//              
//              IWorkspaceName fcwsName = (IWorkspaceName)fc.getFeatureDataset().getWorkspace();
//
                IFeatureClassDescription fcDesc = new FeatureClassDescription();
                IObjectClassDescription ocDesc = (IObjectClassDescription) fcDesc;
//              
//
                gdbFeatureClass = new FeatureClass(featureWorkspace.createFeatureClass(layerInfo.getName(), layerInfo.getFields(), 
                        ocDesc.getInstanceCLSID(), ocDesc.getClassExtensionCLSID(), esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "SHAPE", ""));
//              IFeatureClassName sourceFeatureClassName = new FeatureClassName();
//
//              IFeatureDataConverter2 featureDataConverter = new FeatureDataConverter();
//
//              IEnumInvalidObject enumInvalidObject = featureDataConverter.convertFeatureClass((IDatasetName)fcwsName, 
//                      qf, null,(IFeatureDatasetName)workspaceName, sourceFeatureClassName, 
//                      soeHelper.getGeomRef(fc), 
//                      layerInfo.getFields(), "", 1000, 0);
//
//                      
//              // Check for errors.
//              IInvalidObjectInfo invalidObjectInfo = null;
//              enumInvalidObject.reset();
//              while ((invalidObjectInfo = enumInvalidObject.next()) != null){
//                  // Handle the errors in a way appropriate to the application.
//                  System.out.println("Errors occurred for the following feature: " +
//                          invalidObjectInfo.getInvalidObjectID());
//              }

                    featureCursor = fc.search(qf, true);

                    feature =  featureCursor.nextFeature();             

                    while(feature != null)
                    {                                   
                        newFeature = gdbFeatureClass.createFeature();

                        for (int j = 0; j < featureCursor.getFields().getFieldCount(); j++) 
                        {

                            if(featureCursor.getFields().getField(j).getType() ==  esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeOID)
                            { // skip 
                                continue;
                            }

                            newFeature.setValue(newFeature.getFields().findField(featureCursor.getFields().getField(j).getName()), feature.getValue(j));
                        }

                        newFeature.store();
                        feature =  featureCursor.nextFeature();
                        Cleaner.release(newFeature);
                    }

                    Cleaner.release(gdbFeatureClass);
                    Cleaner.release(featureCursor);
            }

//          Cleaner.releaseAllInCurrentThread();

//          Cleaner.release(gdbFeatureClass);
//          Cleaner.release(featureCursor);     
//          
            soeHelper.releaseSilently(workspaceName);
            soeHelper.releaseSilently(wsName);
            soeHelper.releaseSilently(layerInfos);

            Cleaner.release(featureWorkspace);          
            Cleaner.release(workspace);         
            Cleaner.release(workspaceFactory);

            qf = null;
            workspace = null;
            featureWorkspace = null;
            workspaceFactory = null;
            fc = null;
            layerInfo = null;
            gdbFeatureClass = null;
            newFeature = null;
            feature = null;
            featureCursor = null;

            return fileName;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }


}
```

Comment: Did you try instantiating your workspacefactory using `Activator.CreateInstance` instead of `new` ?  That's the approach Esri recommends. http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/08/18/what-every-arcobjects-programmer-should-know-about-singletons/

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I am writing SOE in java